# docker: Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5000: bind: address already in use

Tags: docker, port

I am new and trying out [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/meetup_kits/getting-started-with-containers-and-kubernetes-a-digitalocean-workshop-kit) from DigitalOcean but when I do `docker run -p 5000:5000 flask_demo:v0`, I am getting the following error.

docker:

```
Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5000: bind: address already in use.
```

Please help me

Comment: Another application already running and listening port `5000` at your development machine

Comment: Exacly what is written. Another service is using that port. Use another port `-p 5001:5000` or find out what is using this port with `netstat` and stop it.

Comment: For MacOs this worked for me https://medium.com/pythonistas/port-5000-already-in-use-macos-monterey-issue-d86b02edd36c

Comment: Hi all, If you have updated your mac os to `Monterey` there it seems like Control Center on Mac OS Monterey is listening on port 5000. You can get it to stop listening by turning off “AirPlay Receiver” in the “Sharing” System Preference https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682332

Comment: Possible solutions
1. Find the process using `lsof -i tcp:5000` and kill the process by running `kill -9 <ProcessID>`
2. If two processes appear when you run the above command then "Airplay" is to be turned off under systempreferences -> sharing.
3. Or else change the port on which you application is supposed to run

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Then you just bind another port

```
docker run -p 5001:5000 flask_demo:v0
```

`-p 5001:5000` basically means, bind port 5001 in my `host machine` with the port 5000 in the container. Since port 5000 already used in your host machine, then u can bind with another port example: port 5001

Comment: Better to find what is already bound to that port. It could easily be another instance of the same container, which OP is not aware is running (very easy to do when just starting out with Docker)

Comment: Thanks, this helped. Now I can see that my simple Hello world is running on local5001.

Comment: @SiHa you can always kill -9 port: 5000 in terminal to kill that port as well

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. Simply pushes it under the rug.

Answer (score 6):

You probably ran the application once before. When a docker container exits, it's still on your machine and has the port allocated.

To see what containers you have, run the command

```
docker ps -a
```

You'll probably see your old container listed and that it's using port 5000.
Remove it with

```
docker rm <container name>
```

Now the port is available again.

If you don't think you'll need to look at your container after it exits, you can add the `--rm` parameter to the docker run command and it'll be automatically removed when it exits. Like this

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 --rm flask_demo:v0
```

Answer (score 1):

To find the program occupying the port, first find what process is occupying the port:

```bash
ss -aultnp | grep 5000
```

Then get the program PID:

```bash
ps -ef | grep pid
```